# Multiply value in the cell by the value on other cell

Tags: excel-formula

Very simple question..
I have a cell ($C$1). There is a value. Now I need to multiply this value with the value from other table's cell ($K$2). What would be the formula?

obviously I cant do this: =$C$1*$K$2. That is the reference to the same cell.

So, what the formula looks like for a cell, that take the value in the same cell and multiply with the value from other cell?

thanks!

Comment: this is a circular reference.  While in Excel it is possible to do this, it can be flakey and may require changing setting in Excel itself on every machine on which this will run and may even depend on that setting being fixed every time one opens excel.  Also that setting would be app wide and not just specific to one cell or sheet.  The best way to do this is through vba in a worksheet_change event.

Comment: so.. there is no way to multiply a value from a cell by a number and assign the value back to that cell? I guess the only way is by the 'change' event... Thanks Scott!

Comment: not consistently and reliably with formula.